# How to save a file response from Webservice in the Server and sent it to Client (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I need to edit a word file provided by a web service and then send it to a client on a click event but i don't know how to do it.

I've search about this but I only found the solutions where the file is directly send to client(with response object). And therefore I Cannot edit it.

So what I'm thinking is a solution where after the button click:

1) Request the File to the Web Service.

2) Get the response file and saved it in a server folder with a specific name.

3) Access the folder and change the word file in the server side.

4) Sent it to client.

5) delete the file from the server.

In this puzzle I know how to do the step 1, 3 and 5 but dont know how to do step 2 and 4.

I'm new to Asp.net and I would be very thankful with the some Help, through code, helping links, or an other way of do what I want.

Thank in Advance

**UPDATE:**

[Image with the flow of what I've described](http://s15.postimg.org/3xvsi0y3f/draw.png)

Comment: where in the process are you sitting in regards to saving the word doucment.. how does the proposed solution work.. does the client request the file how would they know during the button click on their side if the file is even ready or even there..? can you explain the process flow vs what you need ..then I think we could make some suggestions from there..? sometimes it's best to draw out the process flow and see what pieces you need to write and or reuse etc.. then build from there

Comment: Hello @MethodMan, I've just updated. hope it gets clear now